# Creating an If Else loop for multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have the following sub that I wish to run and copy and change formatting for dates which are entered into either F4, G4, or H4. Currently it only does 1 of 3 cells. Was thinking it could be done for all with an OR statement in the If but then the strFull would be wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
Sub CopyDate()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Worksheets("Data Dump")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Worksheets("Daily Cumulations")

ws1.Activate 

Dim TakeDate As String

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = ws2.Range("G" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

' Two different versions
' First is 2006-14-21 for June 14 2021
' Second is 6/14/21 for June 14 2021
    
'**First version
If InStr(Range("H4").Value, "-") <> 0 Then

    Dim strFull As String
    
    strFull = Range("H4").Value
    
    Dim month As String
    Dim dd As String
    Dim yyyy As String
    Dim c As Variant
            
    month = Split(strFull, "-")(0)
    month = Right(month, 2)
            
    dd = Split(strFull, "-")(1)
    yyyy = Split(strFull, "-")(2)
         
    TakeDate = month + "-" + dd + "-" + yyyy
    MsgBox TakeDate
    ws2.Range("G" & lastrow + 1).Value = TakeDate
    TakeDate = CDate(Range("H4").Value)

'**second version?
Else
    TakeDate = Format(Range("H4").Value, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    MsgBox TakeDate
    ws2.Range("G" & lastrow + 1).Value = TakeDate
    TakeDate = CDate(Range("H4").Value)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What format does the cells in discussion may have? Is it a string? Is the text format different in the two sheets, the same range?

Comment: I am trying to deduce the text pattern to return the month like two digits to right of the first array element split by "-"... Are there other strange characters not having anything related to the date in discussion?

Comment: I know converting them to strings are non ideal however given the 2 formats which can be seen in the code, this was a way I got them to fit "date" formats that work with excel date functions. Both formats can be seen in the code also (either / or -)

Comment: Are they all recognised as dates? If so, have you tried just changing the format of the cells.

Comment: My main issue at the moment is not the formatting, its that I need to adapt the code to copy from either cell G4, H4 or F4 and perform all the other same steps